# NextAuth refreshes the whole page when session is updated

Tags: next.js, next-auth, page-refresh, refresh-token

I created the following react hook to handle access tokens when they expired. Simply it checks the token before sending the request and refreshes and updates next auth session if expired.

```
const useAxiosAuth = () = >{
    const axiosAuth = axios.create({
        baseURL: "http://localhost:8080",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        },
    });

    const {
        data: session,
        status,
        update
    } = useSession();
    const router = useRouter();
    axiosAuth.interceptors.request.use(async(req) = >{
        req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer $ {
            session ? .user.access_token
        }`;
        const decoded = jwtDecode(session ! .user.access_token) as any;
        const isExpired = dayjs.unix(decoded.exp).diff(dayjs()) < 1;
        if (!isExpired) {
            return req;
        }
        await axios.post("http://localhost:8080/auth-service/auth/refresh-token", {
            refreshToken: session ? .user.refresh_token,
        }).then(async(res) = >{
            await update({...session,
                user: {...session ? .user,
                    access_token: res.data.access_token,
                    refresh_token: res.data.refresh_token,
                },
            });
            if (session) {
                session.user.access_token = res.data.access_token;
                session.user.refresh_expires_in = res.data.refresh_token;
            }
        }).
        catch((error) = >{
            router.replace(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL + "/auth/login");
        });

        req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer $ {
            session ? .user.access_token
        }`;
        return req;
    },
    (error) = >Promise.reject(error));

    return axiosAuth;
};
```

My  [...nextauth].ts file:

```
import axios from "@/app/lib/axios";
import {
    getCookie
}
from "cookies-next";
import {
    jwtDecode
}
from "jwt-decode";
import {
    NextApiRequest,
    NextApiResponse
}
from "next";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export
default async
    function auth(req:
    NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
        const rememberMeCookie = getCookie("remember-me", {
            req,
            res
        });

        let maxAge = rememberMeCookie === "true" ? 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 : 10 * 60;

        return await NextAuth(req, res, {
            providers: [CredentialsProvider({
                name: "Credentials",
                credentials: {
                    username: {
                        label: "Username",
                        type: "text",
                        placeholder: "username",
                    },
                    password: {
                        label: "Password",
                        type: "password"
                    },
                },
                async authorize(credentials, req) {
                    const res = await axios.post("/auth-service/auth/login", {
                        username: credentials ? .username,
                        password: credentials ? .password,
                    });

                    const user = res.data;

                    if (user) {
                        return user;
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                },
            }), ],
            callbacks: {
                async jwt({
                    token,
                    user,
                    trigger,
                    session
                }: any) {

                    if (trigger === "update") {
                        return {...token,
                            ...session.user
                        }
                    }
                    return {...token,
                        ...user
                    };
                },
                async session({
                    session,
                    token,
                    user
                }) {
                    session.user = token as any;
                    const decoded = jwtDecode(session.user.access_token) as any;
                    session.user.id = decoded.uid;
                    session.user.name = decoded.given_name;
                    session.user.email = decoded.email;
                    session.user.role = decoded.realm_access.roles[0];
                    session.user.username = decoded.preferred_username;
                    if (!session.user.session_expiry) {
                        const exp = new Date(new Date().getTime() + maxAge * 1000).toISOString();
                        session.user.session_expiry = exp;
                    }

                    return session;
                },
                async redirect({
                    url,
                    baseUrl
                }) {
                    return baseUrl + "/admin/home";
                },
            },
            pages: {
                signIn: "/auth/login",
            },
            session: {
                strategy: "jwt",
                maxAge,
                updateAge: 0
            },
            jwt: {
                maxAge,
            },
            secret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
        });
    }
```

All of these working fine.

But when i try to use provider like following to check if session expired or not, nextauth refreshes the whole page. It updates the session but I lose all the page state since it refreshes it.

```
import {
    useSession
}
from "next-auth/react";
import {
    useRouter
}
from "next/navigation";
import {
    ProgressSpinner
}
from "primereact/progressspinner";
interface Props {
    children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Auth = ({
    children
}: Props) = >{
    const router = useRouter();
    const {
        data: sesion,
        status
    } = useSession({
        required: true,
        onUnauthenticated() {
            router.push("/auth/login");
        },
    });

    if (status === "loading") {
        return ( < div className = "w-screen h-screen flex justify-center items-center" > <ProgressSpinner style = {
            {
                width: "50px",
                height: "50px"
            }
        }
        strokeWidth = "8"fill = "var(--surface-ground)"animationDuration = "1s" / ></div>
    );
  }
  return <>{children}</ > ;
    };

    export
default Auth;
```

When I use this component in top of my application like this , it happens.

```
<SessionProvider refetchInterval={5 * 60} refetchOnWindowFocus={true}>
      <Auth>{children}</Auth>
    </SessionProvider>
```

How to prevent this behaviour? I am not experienced with next.js much. So my codes may contain many mistakes. The versions that I am using are:

```
"next": "14.0.1"
"next-auth": "^4.24.5"
```